# Como abrir outro programa java em java e pegar todas as informações que ele manda na console

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Bom estava pesquisando mas nao tive muito sucesso, eu queria abrir um programa java, uma jar, ela nao tem JFrame, ela só manda informações na Console, queria executar ela e pegar essas informações e mandar para ela essas informações tambem, Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt. Lendo sua pergunta acho que seria legal você  editar e reformular o final e se possivel o titulo, pois ficou um pouco confuso :D

Comment: Ficou muito confuso!

Comment: O que você quer é fazer engenharia reversa.

Comment: Se você pesquisou, tenha em mente que a pesquisa em inglês geralmente é mais eficiente. Olhe esta questão no StackOverflow em inglês, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program, particularmente esta resposta, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1320609/1997073, deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado, nao sei muito de inglês, tbm andei pesquisando, mas nao tive sucesso.

Comment: Vou tentar explicar melhor, eu quero abrir um programa java, igual nos abrimos la no cmd, usando scanner, sem ser JFrame(Interface Grafica), esse "programa" quando executado me retorna algumas mensagens eu preciso pega-las e mandar msg para ele tambem. http://prntscr.com/8fx546

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta está um pouco confusa, mas se você quer pegar os dados desse programa você pode tentar executá-lo pelo terminal (console) e atribuir para um arquivo texto.

Exemplo:

```
java -jar Programa.jar > saida.txt
```

Assim, você pode fazer com o que seu código leia esse arquivo texto para aproveitar os dados que o programa em jar gerou.